# Admob ECPM minimum use?

Tags: admob

I Hope this is the correct place to ask for it.

In Admob, you can select an eCPM minimum, but the way I understand that advertising works, advertisers compete for showing one, the advertiser paying the most wins and gets its ad shown.

Right now, I haven't selected a minimum, however, when I select a minimum, 2 competitors might both be above the mimimum and nothing changes for my revenue. On the other hand when I selected a minimum and two competitors are below it, no ad gets shown and I lose revenue.

Therefore my question, what is the point of the eCPM mimimum and in which case can it actually be used for more profit or other benefits?